# CheckBox in DropDownlist Control 

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi friends I am using asp.net,C# I have got a requirement like creating checkbox as item in a dropdownlist. where the items display text i.e checkbox text is generated from database. So any clues in creating a dropdownlist which contains checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

The asp.net DropDownList control does not support this functionality.

Have you looked at the [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) control?

Answer (score -1):

Explore the Properties...of the control. There would be a property called ShowChecked or similar.
The control in consideration might be CheckedListBox

Comment: -1 There is no built-in control called "CheckedListBox" in ASP.NET - you are referring to Windows Forms.